# Converting a sorted list into dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a dictionary, say

`{'name4': 380, 'name2': 349, 'name3': 290, 'name1': 294}`

I have sorted the dictionary based on the values using the `sorted` method and the result is a list of tuples

`[('name3', 290), ('name1', 294), ('name2', 349), ('name4', 380)]`

But, when I try to convert this list of tuples back to dictionary, it's back again to the old structure:

`{'name4': 380, 'name2': 349, 'name3': 290, 'name1': 294}`

I want the sorted list to be made into dictionary as it is. I have used `dict()` and manually used for loop to assign the values. But it's again leading to the same result.

Could anyone help me on this?

Comment: Dictionaries are not ordered (prior to Python 3.6), you may want to pass the sorted items to an `OrderedDict`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python dictionary, how to keep keys/values in same order as declared?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867861/python-dictionary-how-to-keep-keys-values-in-same-order-as-declared)

Answer (score 4):

The keys in a dictionary are, because of the dictionary's underlying structure (hash map), unordered. You have to order the keys yourself when you iterate the keys (i.e. by doing `sorted(dict.keys())` or some other sorting method - if you want to sort by value, you still have to do that manually).

Comment: I would say that ordering the keys when iterating over the dict is probably not the best way.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using an unordered `dict` you could use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) which remembers the the insertion order:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> odict = OrderedDict([('name3', 290), ('name1', 294), ('name2', 349), ('name4', 380)])
>>> odict
OrderedDict([('name3', 290), ('name1', 294), ('name2', 349), ('name4', 380)])
```

It supports the same operations like a normal `dict` (from the documentation of OrderedDict):

> Return an instance of a dict subclass, supporting the usual dict methods. An OrderedDict is a dict that remembers the order that keys were first inserted. If a new entry overwrites an existing entry, the original insertion position is left unchanged. Deleting an entry and reinserting it will move it to the end.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an ordered-dict which maintain the information about the order in which the keys are entered.

```
 OrderedDict({index:i for i, index in enumerate(some_list)})
```

Comment: Could you add more information, like an explanation of the issue and how it's solved, please?

Answer (score -1):

You can refer below code to print the sorted dictionary for the given data:

```
data = [('name3', 290), ('name1', 294), ('name2', 349), ('name4', 380)]

print(sorted(dict(data).items()))
```